# I got ValueError: X has 5851 features per sample; expecting 2754 when applying Linear SVC model to test set

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, nlp, svm

I'm trying to classify texts using Linear SVC, but I got an error.

I applied a model to the test set as below. In this code, I made Tfidf, and did oversampling of training set.

```
#Import datasets
train = pd.read_csv('train_labeled.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

#Clean datasets
custom_pipeline = [preprocessing.fillna,
                   preprocessing.lowercase,
                   preprocessing.remove_whitespace,
                   preprocessing.remove_punctuation,
                   preprocessing.remove_urls,
                   preprocessing.remove_digits,
                   preprocessing.stem  
                   ]



train["clean_text"] = train["text"].pipe(hero.clean, custom_pipeline)
test["clean_text"] = test["text"].pipe(hero.clean, custom_pipeline)

#Create Tfidf

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train["clean_text"])
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

X_test_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(test["clean_text"])
X_test_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_test_counts)

#Oversampling of trainig set
over = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='minority')

X_os, y_os = over.fit_resample(X_train_tfidf, train["label"])

#Model
clf = svm.LinearSVC(C=1.0, penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge', dual=True, tol=1e-3)
clf.fit(X_os, y_os)

pred = clf.predict(X_test_tfidf)
```

and I got an error like this. I think it's because the test set has 5851 samples, but the training set has 2754 samples.

```
ValueError: X has 5851 features per sample; expecting 2754
```

In this case, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: The error message is very clear about the problem. It is *not* about the number of samples, but about the number of features per sample. Without the corresponding code for preprocessing the data, there is no telling what exactly you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `fit_transform()` on the test data as the transformers will learn a new vocabulary and not transform the test data the same way the training data was transformed. To use the same vocabulary as for the training data, use only `transform()` on the test data instead:

```py
# initialize transformers
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()

# fit and transform train data
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train["clean_text"])
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

# transform test data
X_test_counts = count_vect.transform(test["clean_text"])
X_test_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_test_counts)
```

---

**Note**

If you don't need the output of `CountVectorizer`, you could use `TfidfVectorizer` to reduce the amount of code to write:

```py
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()

X_train_tfidf = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(train["clean_text"])
X_test_tfidf = tfidf_vect.transform(test["clean_text"])
```

Comment: Thank you, I put `transform()` on the test data as you said, and I got `NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided`. Could you teach me what I should do in this case?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you should only change the lines relating to the test data. You have to fit the transformers once on the train data with `fit_transform` and then call `transform` on the test data. I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, note that you can reduce the amount of code if you do not need the output of `CountVectorizer`.